# Problem getting bitcoins into Bitcoin Core on Mac

Tags: wallet, bitcoin-core, mac

I'm using Bitcoin Core on a MacBook Pro. A few month ago my computer crashed and I lost everything, so when I got a new computer I reinstalled Bitcoin Core but now I'm having an issue getting my bitcoins to show up in the newly installed Bitcoin Core. I have both the BTC address and the transaction ID under which the bitcoin were transferred to me when I purchased them and I have tried to add both of these on the page where you request payment, without any luck. Not sure what to do to get my bitcoin back as Bitcoin Core has even finished its synchronisation with the network and they are still not showing up...

M

Comment: Just recovered my wallet file. How do I get that into Bitcoin-QT?

Answer (score 1):

You would need a backup of the old wallet.dat from bitcoind, the bitcoin address and transaction information are available to the public. If you were able to recover funds with that information then anyone would be able to 'recover' your coins. Unless you have made a backup you have most likely lost your coins. In the future make sure you always have a backup of your wallet.dat or private keys/seed words (depending on wallet).

Comment: I don't have the wallet.dat file at all and not even sure where to find on the MAC.

Comment: It would be located in ~/Library/Application Support/Bitcoin/    this information can be found at: https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Data_directory

Comment: If you lost everything though I'm not sure you're going to have much luck unless you used a recovery program quickly after losing the data. At this point as far as I know there is not much you can do to recover the coins, they are most likely lost.

Comment: Charles really appreciate all your help. I don't seem to have any backup what so ever, so guess they are lost. To be honest I can't even find the wallet.dat file on my current computer in the location that you are describing.

Comment: Are you sure you are looking in the "Application Support" folder within your home folder, as opposed to the other "Application Support" folder at the root level of your hard disk?

That is, the file is here:
/Users/<your-user-name>/Library/Application Support/Bitcoin/wallet.dat

NOT here:
/Library/Application Support/

Comment: ah maybe... so as I'm the sole user of this mac how do i get to that? I have been looking through finder and can't find the users directory?

Comment: Hi Charles.... just found the wallet.dat file in the location you described (/Users/<your-user-name>/Library/Application Support/Bitcoin/wallet.dat). Sh I guess I need to get that into the bitcoin core program?